# Cancel button call setter getter method in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a screen and there are 2 buttons-Accept and Cancel where user can Acept the value or cancel the value.

```
<div align="center">
    <p:commandButton id="cmdAccept" value="#{label.accept}" action="acceptChange"
        update="certHolderInfo" disabled="#{certHolderDetail.readOnlyHolderInfo}" /> 
    <p:spacer width="10" height="5" />
    <p:commandButton id="cmdCancel" value="#{label.cancel}" action="cancel" />
    <p:spacer width="10" height="5" />
</div>
<p:hotkey bind="Alt+A" action="acceptChange" />
<p:hotkey bind="Alt+C" action="cancel" />
```

When clicking on cancel button it's calling the setter-getter method and update the value of bean. And also when I click on cancel button I am simply going back to previous screen(view) like:

```
<transition on="cancel" to="CMSCertificateHolderInfo" />
```

Ideal condition is that on clicking the cancel button it should not call the setter-getter method of bean. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `process` attribute to specify what components/parts needs to be processed. If you want to process only the button's action, use `process="@this"`.

```
<p:commandButton id="cmdCancel" value="#{label.cancel}" action="cancel" process="@this" />
```